# Short Webspeed Broker Query

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, webspeed

I am trying to create a script that informs the user about the status of the website, which uses WebSpeed. I can use wtbman to output the status of the transaction server, not a problem. But I want something that just tells us the status of the transaction server.

Is there a command that I can use to achieve that, instead of writing a program to parse the returned string for wtbman?

Comment: You are looking for a command and eventually wtbman is also a command. I think you can use wtbman -q for this.This queries the status of the named WebSpeed broker and returns it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in approach like for instance Virtual System Tables.

Parsing the output of

```
wtbman -name <broker> -query
```

is your best bet. The output isn't very hard to decipher so you should be able to do it quite quick!

Two other commands to check are:

```
wtbman -name <broker> -agentdetail <pid>
```

This will go more into detail of a specific agent.

```
wtbman -name <broker> -listallprops
```

Lists all settings for the broker.

Comment: That is pretty much what I did. Unfortunately, this isn't something in mind for Developers. This is for normal users of the website who will want to know if the page is down or not. There are other aspects such as database connection, for which I have managed to develop. So was hoping for something in short for the broker.

Comment: There are most likely better ways for "normal users" to check if the website is up. What could they do if for instance all agents are stopped?

Comment: Accepted your answer as it was the only one I got, plus I did end up parsing it successfully. Cheers mate!